# Android thermal-engine.conf add max freq instead fix values

Tags: kernel

Hello i have an snapdragon 808 wich wents really hot after some hard use...

Today i discovered that the thermal engines wich all roms using on my device is contraproductiv, because it sets a fix value:

[MONITOR-CLUSTER-1]
algo_type      monitor
sampling       5000
sensor         xo_therm_buf
thresholds     42000    4400     46000
thresholds_clr 40000    42000    44000
actions        cluster1 cluster1 cluster1
action_info    1632000  1248000  960000

So if this sensor reaches 42°c the cluster 1 is set permanently to 1632 MHZ even if it's not needed and keep it until threshold or clear reached, that cause higher heating then alternating frequencys.

Is there a possibility to set a max freq value ? So the governor still can decide wich is the right value ?

Answer (score -1):

If your phone is rooted, you can download SetCPU which allows you to set the max frequency.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhuang.overclocking

I've used it for years. Works great for under/over clocking.

Comment: Downvoter, your lack of comment is used helpful and rude. From the OP: "Is there a possibility to set a max freq value?". This addresses that.